# Select highest association when given record's level is random

Tags: sql, database, oracle

There are three tables involved.  DBMS is Oracle 10g.

Employees = individual employee records

- Emp_id (PK)
- Emp_name
- various detail fields

Department = contain hierarchical org structure

- Dept_code (PK)
- Department Name
- Parent_id (refers to dept_code in same table for parent dept)
- depth_level (1=highest level, 2=sub-depts of 1, etc ...  max = 6)
- various details fields

Association = mapping employees to departments

- Assoc_id (pk)
- emp_id (fk)
- dept_code (fk)
- other fields that relate different association types

Where the association maps employees to departments at various depths, I want to run a query that counts all employees grouped at depth = 2.  If an employee works in a dept at level 6, I would need to resolve level 5, then level 4, then level 3 to get to level 2, but if they work in a dept at level 3, I only need to resolve to level 2.

Trying to figure out the most efficient way.  So far, I'm looking at running 5 separate queries, one for each depth with varying numbers of subqueries to resolve the depth levels and then combining with union.  My second thought was to create a static reference table to map each department code to a level 2 label, but maintaining that table would be problematic.

Anybody got any better ideas?

Comment: It seems that you need some [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm). Could you attach some code, that we know what you are doing? And desired output? Your  question title and this part: _"I want to run a query that counts all employees"_ are little confusing. Any details are valuable.

Comment: I see your point, I meant that I wanted to be able to group records at the highest level, whether I count employees or list them, the point being to aggregate them at a given level.  I just solved the problem moments ago using recursive CTE which was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive CTE saved the day.  I apologize if my question wasn't clear, here is my solution although I may have changed some of the field names from the original post.  I plan to replace the static value for U.ID in the first part of the union query with a parameter that will any department code and retrieve its respective subordinate departments.

In this case dept code '5000002' is the IT department, the results display all employees in various levels of the IT department hierarchy.

```
select r.full_name, r.id, u.dept_name, u.dept_id, u.dept_level
from clarity.srm_resources r,
clarity.PRJ_OBS_ASSOCIATIONS a,
(with DIRECT_DEPT (Parent_ID, Dept_ID, Dept_Name, Dept_Level)
as
(
SELECT U.PARENT_ID, U.ID AS DEPT_ID, U.NAME AS DEPT_NAME, 0 AS Dept_Level
FROM  clarity.prj_obs_units u
where u.type_id = '5000001'
AND U.ID = '5000002'
UNION ALL
SELECT U.PARENT_ID, U.ID AS DEPT_ID, U.NAME AS DEPT_NAME, Dept_Level +1
FROM  clarity.prj_obs_units u
INNER JOIN DIRECT_DEPT D
ON U.PARENT_ID = D.DEPT_ID
where u.type_id = '5000001'
)
SELECT Parent_ID, Dept_ID, Dept_Name, Dept_Level
FROM DIRECT_DEPT) u
where a.record_id = r.id
and a.unit_id = u.dept_id
and a.table_name ='SRM_RESOURCES'
and r.is_active = '1'
;
```